# Carbon crack or cosmetic damage?

Tags: carbon, crack

I have a new bike and after a bikefit (it was causing me kneepain) I had to raise the saddle and noticed a crack. I only use a torque wrench and tighten it to 4Nm usually so I can't overtighten (4.5 - 5.5). Can someone tell me if I should be worried? [image]

Comment: I do not see anything crack-like. What place specifically are you worried about?

Comment: That thing at the bottom  looks like a paint defect to me.

Comment: It is the thing on the bottom, unfortunately I could only include one picture. I can feel it with my nail if I go over it. I think it is probably nothing too, but I am new to carbon and still a bit on edge I guess!

Comment: Which part of the bike is that?

Comment: Around the seatpost, it's the tightening bolt for the seat that is shown.

Comment: This is under the top tube, right? I’d contact the frame manufacturer, it’s quite likely this is a paint defect they missed in quality control. To the left the paint doesn’t look good either.

Comment: It is on top of the top tube, at the front of the seatpost. If you tighten the bolt it pushes a clamp mechanism against the seatpost to keep it secure. https://cdn.road.cc/sites/default/files/styles/main_width/public/2021-giant-tcr-advanced-pro-1-disc-seat-post-bolt.jpg

Comment: It did a little but I went to the shop where I bought it (I had already been to my LBS but they were also not sure). The shop took a more thorough look and concluded paint damage as well! Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

Been to the bike shop that sold me it and they confirmed the cosmetic damage only.